# In Spring Boot while annotating a class then every method gets annotated with same annotation

Tags: java, spring-boot

In Spring Boot while annotating a class with some annotation(e.g. @Component, @Service, @Entity ..... so on) then every method gets annotated with same annotation. Please explain it will be help full for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the annotations that you have mentioned are class level annotations. Annotations are not copied they just remain there and used by that element only.

If you see the Javadoc of a particular annotation then you will find all annotations have been annotated with @Target having parameter of ElementType. This enum defines the type of annotation.

But there are also some annotation like @Transactional , that are used by the methods called from the parent method having this annotation and this annotation is guided by @Inherited annotation that give it this functionality.

```
public enum ElementType {
    /** Class, interface (including annotation type), or enum declaration */
    TYPE,

    /** Field declaration (includes enum constants) */
    FIELD,

    /** Method declaration */
    METHOD,

    /** Formal parameter declaration */
    PARAMETER,

    /** Constructor declaration */
    CONSTRUCTOR,

    /** Local variable declaration */
    LOCAL_VARIABLE,

    /** Annotation type declaration */
    ANNOTATION_TYPE,

    /** Package declaration */
    PACKAGE
}
```

I suggest you to see the Javadoc of annotations, you will find many concepts there.

Answer (score 0):

Annotations are at the end, java code abstracted form you.

So, it will depend on the implementation of the particular annotation, whether the code against it, applies to every method, or only to the class.

- `@override` applies only to method
- `@component` applies to class, behaviour affects enclosing methods too
- `@PathVariable` applies at method arguments only

---

To further enrich your concepts

https://www.baeldung.com/java-custom-annotation